# How do I persist login state for a user between my website and my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I built a Chrome Extension, where a login form is displayed as a side bar using content scripts injection. I do not want the user to see this login form if the user is already logged in on the website and vice versa if the user logs in on the Chrome Extension and then visits the website, user should automatically log in.

I am returning tokens from the backend when a user successfully logs in.

My question is, what is the best way to store these tokens so both the content scripts in my extension and the website have access to the token to check to see if the user is already logged in.

As far as I understand I have localStorage, ChromeStorage but I do not know if they are shared between the tabs of the browser and the extension.

Any direction is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're returning tokens, a reasonable way to do it would be to inject a content script into pages that match the callback URL containing the token, extract it and save into `chrome.storage`. It is shared between the content script and all other extension contexts.

Do note: `chrome.storage` is not exactly secure: it's not encrypted on disk, and can be snooped upon with Dev Tools. Then again, the token is normally stored in the cookie store, which can be likewise examined even without access to the (slightly) more secure password storage.

Perhaps the only more secure way to keep the token in the extension is `chrome.identity` API, but then you have to login separately, defeating your goal.

Comment: thanks. I am injecting the side bar on other webpages using content script. Not my website page. You think I can use chrome.cookies in the background page to extract the cookie from my website and then store it in chrome.storage, which I then access in my content script as content script has access to chrome.storage api?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that. My reasoning was to get notified about login immediately.

Comment: Your reasoning is on point too. In my scenario, I only load content script when user clicks on a browser action so I do not need to get immediately notified. Thanks a bunch though. You send me in the right direction.