# share cookies between a chrome website and chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a webapp which uses JWT tokens to identify the user.

With the webapp built now i need to build a chrome browser extension (brand new to extensions).

The browser extension needs to know who the user is, it must act in the same way as the web app and use a JWT token to fetch and send data to the APIs.

In the ideal world, the user would login once to either the chrome extension or web app but in this one action be logged into both.

**Question:**
Is it possible to share cookies between a chrome website and chrome extension?

Similar question but 5 years old:

> [How do I persist login state for a user between my website and my chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171848/how-do-i-persist-login-state-for-a-user-between-my-website-and-my-chrome-extensi)

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/

Comment: Cookies are sent automatically with XMLHttpRequest. To use them with `fetch` use `credentials` option.

Comment: For anyone else who hits this issue.. it seems the menifest.json url must end with a slash

Comment: @wOxxOm how does the cookies are stored in the first place? should I use chrome.tab.create to open the signup page where cookies are stored, so that I can always read the cookies from my extension?